# How do I change this MATLAB code into python?

Tags: python

[This is the MATLAB code I am trying to do in python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsoLN.png)
This is what I have on python:
import numpy
import math

```
t=numpy.linspace(0,2,16000)

def soundone(t):

  return math.sin(2*math.pi*440*t)

def soundtwo(t):
```

return math.sin*(2*math.pi*880*t)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

ax.plot(t, soundone)

ax.plot(t,soundtwo)

plot.show()
```

I keep getting the error that these have different dimensions, how do I make it so my plot only shows the first 1/100th of

Comment: Your Python code does not make sense and would not run because it is not indented properly. Please reproduce indentation accurately if you post Python code.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 0):

`soundone` and `soundtwo` are functions, not arrays.  You need something like `ax.plot(t, soundone(t))` or better yet `soundone = math.sin(2*math.pi*440*t)` instead of the `def` blocks.

And you can do the plot on one line, `ax.plot(t, soundone, t, soundtwo)`